# How to write query string in bash?

Tags: bash, sqoop

I am trying to build a query string in bash to execute in a sqoop command.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  d1=$(date +'%Y%m')
  STR="Select * from Table1 where dtmn = "
  Query=$STR$d1
```

Now if I use this it will select * from my directory vs build this as a string.  If I use \ to escape then when I call it using echo I get:

```
  d1=$(date +'%Y%m')
  STR="Select \* from Table1 where dtmn = "
  Query=$STR$d1
  echo $Query

  ['Select \\* from Table1 where dtmn = 202006']
```

This breaks in my sqoop command as soon as it gets to the \.

What do I need to do to dynamically build this query string in bash based on the date, and execute it in a sqoop command?

Comment: You can't have spaces around `=` in bash assignments.

Comment: Always quote your variables: `echo "$Query"`

Comment: The spaces are not in the code and mistakenly typed out when posting the question.  I think I fixed in in the question though.

Comment: As an aside, you can put the entire query in the argument to `date`: `Query=$(date +'select * from table1 where dtmn = %Y%m')`.